# django: csrf_token for multiple forms and ajax requests on a single page

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, csrf, django-csrf

My website has a single page with 2 forms and 3 ajax-based POST calls. I have used `csrf_token` in one of the forms. Also, to be able to perform csrf-safe ajax calls, I am using the guidelines posted on the official documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/csrf/ and this blog: https://realpython.com/blog/python/django-and-ajax-form-submissions/

As suggested, by using this peice of code https://gist.github.com/broinjc/db6e0ac214c355c887e5 in my javascript file, it seems I am able to perform POST requests without any problems.

Questions:

1. Is using `csrf_token` in one of the forms along with the javascript code (mentioned above) sufficient to ensure csrf forgery? Should I be using `csrf_token` in the second form?
2. As suggested in this SO post [Generating CSRF tokens for multiple forms on a single page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14715250/generating-csrf-tokens-for-multiple-forms-on-a-single-page) it seems using same token should be fine. However, just to be clear, I am using `{% csrf_token %}` in my first form and not a hidden field as mentioned in the post. And I am not using any `csrf_token` in my second form.
3. Should I be doing anything extra for my ajax calls or are they fine?
4. Is there a way to check in `views.py` function that the call is `csrf` safe?

Let me know if you need more information and I will be happy to elaborate further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is using csrf_token in one of the forms along with the javascript code (mentioned above) sufficient to ensure csrf forgery? Should I be
>   using csrf_token in the second form?

I hope not ;) Enabling the `CsrfViewMiddleware` in Django is sufficient to ensure that your views are protected *against* cross-site request forgery. If you use two separate HTML forms (two `<form></form>` tags), both forms need to have a hidden CSRF token field. If you use two Django forms in a single `form` tag, you only need it once.

If that javascript snippet would send the token with any request, not just AJAX requests, you would only need the token once, but I don't believe it does, so you need it in each HTML form.

> As suggested in this SO post Generating CSRF tokens for multiple
>       forms on a single page it seems using same token should be fine.
>       However, just to be clear, I am using {% csrf_token %} in my first
>       form and not a hidden field as mentioned in the post. And I am not
>       using any csrf_token in my second form.

The `{% csrf_token %}` tag creates a hidden field for you, so essentially you *are* using a hidden field.

> Should I be doing anything extra for my ajax calls or are they fine?

The javascript you included sets a header to the value of the CSRF token on every AJAX request. This header replaces the post data that is usually sent by the hidden field in a form. Any AJAX calls you send through jQuery will have this header, you won't need to do anything else.

> Is there a way to check in views.py function that the call is csrf safe?

Not really. As long as you have the `CsrfViewMiddleware` enabled and you're not using the `csrf_exempt` decorator, your view is protected. If the call is unsafe, the middleware will return a `403 Forbidden` response before the request even reaches the view.