# CSRF Token missing or invalid. -> First form fails other CSRF Token work

Tags: ajax, django, csrf

So I have a site with multiple buttons. These buttons are inside forms and use this { CSRF }. However the first button won't work.

This is a snippet of how the HTML looks like.

```
<form  method="post" id="post-form">
                      {% csrf_token %}
                      <button type="submit" name="startVm" class="btn btn-default btn-block d-none d-md-block">StartVM</button>
                </form>
                <form  method="post" id="post-form">
                      {% csrf_token %}
                      <button type="submit" name="stopVm" class="btn btn-default btn-block d-none d-md-block">StopVM</button>
                </form>
```

And this is the Ajax function that I use.

```
$('#post-form').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("form submitted!")  // sanity check
        post();
    });
    // AJAX for posting
    function post() {
        console.log("create post is working!") // sanity check
        $.ajax({
            url : '', // the endpoint
            type : 'post', // http method
            data : {},
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            processData: true,
            // handle a successful response
            success : function() {
               alert("Thank you for your comment!");
                console.log("success"); // another sanity check
            },

            // handle a non-successful response
            error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
                $('#results').html("<div class='alert-box alert radius' data-alert>Oops! We have encountered an error: "+errmsg+
                    " <a href='#' class='close'>&times;</a></div>"); // add the error to the dom
                console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); // provide a bit more info about the error to the console
            }
        });
    };
```

So as I said. The button StartVM won't work and it returns a 403 error.(Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /)
The second one however works without a problem.

This is the code in the view.py

```
def post (self, request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'startVm' in request.POST:
        print("startVM button")
        return HttpResponse("{}",
        content_type='application/json', status=204)
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'stopVm' in request.POST:
        print("stopVM button");
        return HttpResponse("{}",
        content_type='application/json', status=204)
    return HttpResponse("{}",
    content_type='application/json')
```

I am returning status 204 because e.preventDefault() won't work and it refreshes the whole site if I click on a button.

Comment: A similar problem was discussed before here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31866435/django-csrf-token-for-multiple-forms-and-ajax-requests-on-a-single-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, ids should be unique, but you have `id="post-form"` on two separate forms.

You could do `class="post-form"` instead, and change your JS to use `.post-form`.

Or, for the template in your question, you could have a single `<form>` tag that contains both buttons.

Next, you need to include the CSRF token *inside* the form data.

```
data : {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
```

Alternatively, you could follow the [suggestion](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/csrf/#ajax) in the docs, and add an `X-CSRFToken` header for ajax requests, then you don't need to include the token in the post data.

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful!